# How to dual boot ubuntu and OS X using a virtual image?

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, boot-camp, vmware-fusion

Is it possible using bootcamp or some other way to install ubuntu using an virtual image made in VmWare, so that it can be dual booted and run on my physical hdd. 
if so how?